Geo Nodes: store attribute "line length" for every point in the line
I am creating a Mesh Line, and calculate the distance between point x and point x-1 to store it as a named attribute. Based on that distance I want to calculate the length of the line at that point. In the first screenshot I calculated and added the length attribute by hand.

The only solution I found to calculate the length is by using a Repeat Zone, but iterating over the 10 points seems to be a little laborious to me.

Is there a better way to archive what I want? Thank you in advance!

Pretty sure you wanna use an Accumulate Field node

Convert to curve, capture lengths and convert back to mesh?

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
For a chain of edges, a Shortest Edge Paths node should be enough :


Ok that is pretty easy. Thank you.
